# Essential singularities of $\exp(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Could you explain to me why $z = \infty$ is an essential singularity of function $\exp(z)$  ?

What about $z$ = 0, is it essential singularity?

Comment: Adressing your update: no. Simply $\exp(0)=1$. There is no singularity at all at $0$ (at most you could call it a removable singularity).

Comment: With your additional question, did you mean to ask about $\exp(1/z)$ at $z=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $z\to\infty$ along the positive real axis then $\exp(z)\to\infty$.

If $z\to\infty$ along the negative real axis then $\exp(z)\to0$.

If $z\to\infty$ along the imaginary axis then $\exp(z)$ oscillates between $1$ and $-1$.

So $\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}\exp(z)$ does not exist within $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$.